# Check a Pentaho result every 30 minutes and run other steps

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I am new to Pentaho. I currently has a job like this:

```
condition 1 -> condition 2 -> if successful then run this sql scripts, if failed then send email
```

I would like to have a loop that is more like:

```
(condition 1 -> condition -> 2) are run every 30 minutes 
-> if successful then run the sql scripts  and stop going back to conditions to check
-> if failed then loop back and run in the next interval
```

Is this possible to achieve?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a job. See screenshots.

You'll need to replace the simple evaluation step by your condition checking routine.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello thank you for your answer. How do I set the Start? Should it be no scheduling and just run once?

Comment: Call it from the command line?

Answer (score 0):

You could program a job to run every 30 minutes and add a step generating a file or inserting/updating a DB table that you could use to check if you need to run the conditions or not.